# Count large data based on status in the columns using procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, count, mariadb, large-data

There are 7.7M records (and growing rapidly) in the table and it is taking up to 19 seconds to count all records.

My requirement is to load it within 1 sec please help me ....

My table structure is ->

```
id  |campaign_id  | disposition |   action    create_date | more 16 columns...
1   |     3       |   CANCEL    |     NULL    2020-08-12  |
2   |     5       |   ANSWER    |     DNC     2020-08-13  |
3   |     3       |   ANSWER    |     SIP     2020-08-14  |
```

My procedure is ->

```
proc_campaign_report(campaignId int(10), reportTable varchar(20))
BEGIN
 SET @SELECTFROM = CONCAT("
        select  create_date as dialDate, count(id) as calls, sum(duration) as duration,
                sum(client_cost) as clientCost, sum(vendor_cost) as vendorCost,
                count(case when action = 'DNC' then 1 end) as dontCall,
                count(case when action = 'AM' then 1 end) as am,
                count(case when action in ('SIP',
                                'Hangup','Phone') then 1 end) as transfer,
                count(case when disposition = 'ANSWER' then 1 end
                     ) as answer,
                count(case when disposition = 'CONGESION' then 1 end) as congesion,
                count(case when disposition = 'BUSY' then 1 end) as busy,
                count(case when disposition = 'CANCEL' then 1 end) as cancel,
                count(case when disposition = 'NO ANSWER' then 1 end) as noAnswer,
                count(case when disposition is NULL then 1 end) as other,
                count(case when disposition = 'FAILED' then 1 end) as failed
            from  ",reportTable 
                         );
SET @SELECTWHERE = CONCAT('
            where  `campaign_id` =', campaignId 
                         );
SET @SELECTQUERY = CONCAT(@SELECTFROM,
                @SELECTWHERE 
                         );
SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@SELECTQUERY, '
            group by  `dialDate`
            order by  `dialDate` desc
            limit  3'
                   );
PREPARE stmt
    FROM  @QUERY;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

please suggest me if there is any work around.....

I tried indexing too but it does't give me the proper result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by finding the 3rd newest dialDate for that `campaignId`.  Then add to the `WHERE` clause `AND dialDate >= @third`

Also have this composite index: `INDEX(campaignId, dialDate)`

If that does not help enough, then provide

- The generated query.  (I can be tricky to follow the concats.)
- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`